# Differences between .insertAdjacentHTML and .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

What are differences to consider when choosing between the `.insertAdjacentHTML` and `.innerHTML` methods? What are compelling use-cases for each? Which has better performance and in what situations? How does `.innerHTML` work? Are there other alternatives?

Comment: The two are quite different. The reason to use one over the other depends on the situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few benefits `.insertAdjacentHTML` has over `.innerHTML`. The first of which is performance. In a benchmarking test performed, `.innerHTML` appended slightly over 200 Twitter tweets in five full seconds. `insertAdjacentHTML`, on the other hand appended nearly 30,000 in the same time-frame.  The more data that needed to be appended, the worse `.innerHTML` performed. Note however, in this case, data was appended using `.innerHTML +=`.

Another benefit is control. `.insertAdjacentHTML` provides you with control over where you want to append data, while `.innerHTML does not.

The final benefit of `.insertAdjacentHTML` is  it does not corrupt the DOM. Here is how `.innerHTML +=` works.

1. It gets the value of `.innerHTML` by serializing the descendants of
   element.
2. It appends the right hand side of += to the string.
3. It removes the children of element.
4. It parses the new string that
   contains the serialization of the old descendants followed by some
   new markup.
   Obviously, the last benefit does not really apply in the case of using `.innerHTML =`.

Other alternatives to `.innerHTML` are the `.insertBefore` method, which as its name suggests inserts a node as a child before another node, as well as the `.appendChild` method which inserts a child node as the last node.

`.insertAdjacentHTML` is something of a multi-functional tool seeing as it can perform the jobs of `.innerHTML`, `.insertBefore`, as well as `.appendChild`.

Sources: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/insertadjacenthtml-enables-faster-html-snippet-injection/

Comment: Your question says nothing of using `+=` with `.innerHTML`, so I'm not sure why your answer deals specifically with that situation. It's almost like you didn't read your own question.

Comment: I edited the question, and am currently doing the same for the answer.